# Useeffect not getting called immedietly as dependency value changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, mern

I am very new to react. I am experimenting with react and trying to undertand it's concepts right now.

I have a component that has two states,Name and room. I am using setstate to set room and name values, I have a 2 useeffects 1st one runs at initial render and gets the name and room value. second one is supposed to render as soon name or room changes

```
const Chat = ({location}) => {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
    const [userRoom, setUserRoom] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log("initial use effect called")
        const {name,room} = queryString.parse(location.search)
        setUserName(name)
        setUserRoom(room)
    }, [])
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('name or room changed')
    },[userName,userRoom])
    return (

        <div>
           component
        </div>
    )
}
```

Since I am setting name and room one after another I expected second use effect to be called three times

(first time on initial render,second time when name changes,third time when room changes)

but it is only called twice.
Also, if I add a timeout in initial useeffect,

second useeffect get called three times

```
const Chat = ({location}) => {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
    const [userRoom, setUserRoom] = useState("");
    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log("initial use effect called")
        const {name,room} = queryString.parse(location.search)
        setUserName(name)
        setTimeout(()=>{
        setUserRoom(room)
          },0)
        
    }, [])
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log('name or room changed')
    },[userName,userRoom])
    return (

        <div>
           component
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: with timeout, state updates are no longer batched; hence you get one more execution of `useEffect` hook

Answer (score 4, accepted):

React does state updates in batches. Which means, when you are setting state multiple times, it will update both the state in a single operation, resulting in reduced re-rending (which is good in most of the cases). You can learn more about this [here](https://medium.com/swlh/react-state-batch-update-b1b61bd28cd2).

Answer (score 1):

When `setState` is called multiple times in **React event handler or synchronous lifecycle method**, it will be batched into a single update. That's why you are getting two logs, **initial render causes first log and setState causes second log** and when you called `useState` inside `setTimeOut` then it logged as you expected because `setTimeOut` **is an asynchronous operation** and it behaves like this with other asynchronous operations such as `async/await, then/catch, fetch,` etc. **because Separate state updates will not be batched in asynchronous operations**.